# Does the Maven Assembly Plugin (maven-assembly-plugin) support the EAR format?

Tags: maven, ear, maven-assembly-plugin, maven-ear-plugin

Does the maven-assembly-plugin support EAR as a valid format? The documentation seems to indicate you can configure it any way you want:

> - zip
> - tar.gz
> - tar.bz2
> - jar
> - dir
> - war and any other format that the ArchiveManager has been configured for

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Comment: Why not just use the maven-ear-plugin to generate an ear?

Comment: Because then it forces you to use the "Maven way" for structuring your EAR, with the WAR and EJBs as separate modules. The thought is that if I use the assembly plugin I will have more control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. Just specify in your assembly descriptor:

```
<formats>
  <format>ear</format>
</formats>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can but you should use the maven-ear-plugin instead, cause it know better about ejbs etc. of which maven-assembly-plugin doesn't know anything about.