# Create an EAR using Maven

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

I want to create an EAR using Maven, but since I'm in a pure Tycho world, I can't use the `maven-ear-plugin`, just the `maven-assembly-plugin` (which is fine).

There are [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10787010/create-an-ear-with-maven-assembly-plugin) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611640/does-the-maven-assembly-plugin-maven-assembly-plugin-support-the-ear-format) even on this very site that indicate that the `maven-assembly-plugin` can build EARs, even though the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) says no.

However, when I use define the EAR format like this:

```
<formats>
    <format>ear</format>
</formats>
```

I get the following exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.0:single (make-assembly) on project org.acme.application: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive default: appxml attribute is required -> [Help 1]

(I tried a couple of versions for the `maven-assembly-plugin`, so it's not that.)

Since a EAR is just a renamed JAR, I'm now using the JAR format and this other Maven plug-in:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.coderplus.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>copy-rename-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>rename-ear</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>rename</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <sourceFile>${basedir}/target/${earName}.jar</sourceFile>
                <destinationFile>${basedir}/target/${earName}.ear</destinationFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Which works nicely in creating an EAR, however with `mvn install` it brings the following exception:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) on project org.acme.application: Failed to install artifact group:org.acme.application:jar:1.9.126-SNAPSHOT: C:\workspace\Application\target\Application.jar (Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden) -> [Help 1]

(It's German for "Cannot find file", one day I'll get him to print out readable error messages.)

Of course, now I could copy the JAR to an EAR instead of just renaming it, but I thought I get a 2nd oppinion first: Is it possible to create an EAR with the `maven-assembly-plugin`? If so, how?

Comment: Use the packaging type `<packaging>ear</packaging>` and define the dependencies in the ear module on the jar's and that will work also for OSGi...Apart from that make an simple example project which has 2-3 module (OSGi) put that on Github so we can have a look at it...

Comment: @khmarbaise I can't use that packing type, because the EAR is build out of the contents of a feature (the packaging type is `eclipse-feature`).

Comment: I know but you can add the resulting jar file as a jar module in EAR configuration...

Comment: @khmarbaise Nope, because that would need a Maven depedency. I can only copy the files out of other project's _targets/_ folders.